# How to print the value of a sub-string each time it occurs in another string in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore

I'm working on a qt project, I have a sub-string and I want to search for this string in another string and print it each time it occurs.
I have a string 1234-1456-11234-1 I want to print a each time I found 1234-1
I used the function contains but it prints the sub-string once not each time it occurs.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by print?

Comment: not necessary print its not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [indexOf](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qstring.html#indexOf) method as follows:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QString substring("substring");
    QString string("foosubstringbarsubstringbazsubstringhellosubstringworld");
    for (int i = 0; (i = string.indexOf(substring, i)) != -1; ++i)
            qDebug() << string.mid(i);
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
"substringbarsubstringbazsubstringhellosubstringworld"
"substringbazsubstringhellosubstringworld"
"substringhellosubstringworld"
"substringworld"
```